# Query executed from Nhibernate is slow, but from ADO.NET is fast

Tags: sql-server, performance, nhibernate, ado.net

I have a query in my MVC application which takes about 20 seconds to complete (using NHibernate 3.1). When I execute the query manually on Management studio it takes 0 seconds.

I've seen similiar questions on SO about problems similar to this one, so I took my test one step further.

I intercepted the query using Sql Server Profiler, and executed the query using ADO.NET in my application.

The query that i got from the Profiler is something like: "exec sp_executesql N'select...."

My ADO.NET code:

```
SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection) NHibernateManager.Current.Connection;

var query = @"<query from profiler...>";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

This query is also very fast, taking no time to execute.

Also, I've seen something very strange on the Profiler. The query, when executed from NH, has the following statistics:

reads: 281702
writes: 0

The one from ADO.NET:

reads: 333
writes: 0

Anyone has any clue? Is there any info I may provide to help diagnose the problem?

I thought it might be related to some connection settings, but the ADO.NET version is using the same connection from NHibernate.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I'm using NHibernate LINQ. The query is enormous, but is a paging query, with just 10 records being fetched.

The parameters that are passed to the "exec sp_executesql" are:

@p0 int,@p1 datetime,@p2 datetime,@p3 bit,@p4 int,@p5 int

@p0=10,@p1='2009-12-01 00:00:00',@p2='2009-12-31 23:59:59',@p3=0,@p4=1,@p5=0

Comment: do you use futures or multicriterias in the NHib code?

Comment: Try using nhprof, maybe NH is issuing other queries afterwards, possibly an N+1 issue.

Comment: Hi, there is just one query. I've already used NHProf

Comment: @Firo: No, not at this query.

Comment: Quite likely parameter sniffing. See ["Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?"](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @Martin: I though so too initially, but my ADO.NET test also ran the same query from the web app, including the same parameters, and it was fast

Comment: @psousa - Capture the execution plans for both. Pretty sure you will discover that for one reason or another they are using different plans.

Comment: @Martin: I've done it, but they're gigantic. Is there anything in particular that I should look for?

Comment: @psousa - Mouse over the arrows in the slow plan and look for big (order of magnitude) discrepancies between actual and estimated number of rows and try and trace this to the root operator. You can use winmerge or similar to compare the XML to see differences also.

Comment: @MartinSmith: They were indeed different. Not sure why, but could be related to one sending a "sp_executesql" and the other an EXEC SQL. Anyway, it's not really important as I also discovered it was indeed Parameter sniffing (as you suggested), and one of the plans was optimized for a large dataset, and the other one not. So, it was just a matter of solving the parameter sniffing on the NH query (which is itself worthy of a SO question). Please post an answer with your previous suggestions so I can accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the ADO.NET and NHibernate using different query-plans, and I was sufering the effects of parameter sniffing on the NH version. Why? Because I had previously made a query with a small date interval, and the stored query-plan was optimized for it.

Afterwards, when querying with a large date interval, the stored plan was used and it took ages to get a result.

I confirmed that this was in fact the problem because a simple:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE -- clears the query-plan cache
```

made my query fast again.

I found 2 ways to solve this:

- Injecting an "option(recompile)" to the query, using a NH Interceptor
- Adding a dummy predicate to my NH Linq expression, like:  `query = query.Where(true)` when the expected result-set was small (date interval wise). This way two different query plans would be created, one for large-sets of data and one for small-sets.

I tried both options, and both worked, but opted for the second approach. It's a little bit *hacky* but works really well I my case, because the data is uniformly distributed date-wise.

Comment: I'd like to point out that "DBCC FREEPROCCACHE" clears the entire cache.  This may be more than you bargained for in a system with lots of things going on (sic live environment).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25070902/69809) has an example of how to use an interceptor to add `OPTION OPTIMIZE FOR @p UNKNOWN` to the end of the query.

Comment: Rather than tweaking the query, optimizing indexes can solve this issue too. Adjusting indexes should be the preferred way in my opinion. Parameter sniffing causes issues mainly when there are inadequate indexes for the query (or lack of indexes). But sometime it is hard to have sound indexes for all queries.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem as the OP.  I tried @psousa's suggestion of injecting an "option(recompile)" which did improve my performance.  But in the end I found that simply updating statistics on SQL Server did the trick for me.

```
update statistics tablename;
```

I ended up backing out my code to inject the "option(recompile)".  I realize this may not be the answer for everyone, but wanted to share since it was the cause of my problems.

Comment: @SkipHarris So fa so good. This has yielded a dramatic improvement for me `_sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().CreateSQLQuery("update statistics [tablename];").ExecuteUpdate();`

Answer (score 2):

Look at the parameters being supplied to the sp_executesql stored proc. If the parameters are supplied as nvarchar (N'value') and the columns they reference are varchar, SQL Server will use a very inefficient query plan. This has been the root cause of all the performance issues I've had that exhibit these symptoms (slow in app., fast in SSMS).

Comment: That's a nice tip, but unfortunately no. The parameters are: @p0 int,@p1 datetime,@p2 datetime,@p3 bit,@p4 int,@p5 int',@p0=10,@p1='2009-12-01 00:00:00',@p2='2009-12-31 23:59:59',@p3=0,@p4=1,@p5=0"

Comment: Also, in my second test the app is fast, but using ADO.NET directly instead of NH.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify your query or the size of its resultset, but there's an issue with fetching large number of entities with nHibernate.
basically, the time to 'hydrate' the objects is what's taking that long.
you can try turning on the reflection optimizer, or using an IStatelessSession.
see som suggestions that i've got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664113/nhibernate-performance-issue-when-loading-large-collections).

Comment: Actually no, because the times that I'm comparing are from Sql Server Profiler (column "duration"), before the data is even hydrated.