# NHibernate SQL query are getting slower

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, query-performance

I'm building system that needs to process all product data from the database (right now testing with 200k products + data spread across multiple tables).

I use NHibernate to do all the queries. 
I've created a custom query that can fetch all related data for a list of ProductIds in one go (trying to find the best cut in which i query data most efficient). 

Right now i'm struggeling with the fact that it on some queries takes up to 5 minutes to complete and in best cases 2 seconds. (remember it's the exact same query for the same number of products ids). This is a test run where i fetch 200 complete products each loop. A log shows (in my eyes) pretty random query times:

> Grabbing 200 products from the database took: 00:00:01.9370364
>   seconds.
>  Grabbing 200 products from the database took:
>   00:01:06.8207146 seconds.
>  Grabbing 200 products from the database
>   took: 00:00:58.5194938 seconds.
>  Grabbing 200 products from the
>   database took: 00:00:03.5447583 seconds.
>  Grabbing 200 products
>   from the database took: 00:02:01.6096919 seconds.
>  Grabbing 200
>   products from the database took: 00:00:03.2856333 seconds.
>   Grabbing 200 products from the database took: 00:02:04.8108302
>   seconds.
>  Grabbing 200 products from the database took:
>   00:00:03.4525576 seconds.
>  Grabbing 200 products from the database
>   took: 00:01:04.4530670 seconds.

Above is just a cut-out so please don't try to find a pattern in that because it is random. Sometimes it runs 10 queries in a row with acceptable query times and sometimes it's only every second query. Eventually it times out.

It seems to be query time in the database - i've also attached a sql profiler which shows the same long query times.

I'm not doing anything else while running the code. I've set the isolation level to ReadCommitted - setting it lower doesn't seem to affect the query time.

I guess the question is: Which things should i look for in order to alter the performance? I'm using a sql server enterprise 2012 64 bit version.

I'm not a big fan of altering the query or the database schema since it doesn't seems to be related?

Any suggestions are welcome though.

Best regards

Morten

Comment: You say you have same results on SQL profiler (its not attached btw), this means that it is the database, how can it be Nhibernate? I would most definitely install NHProfiler as this can show you a magnitude of information (stats) which will help.

Comment: Attached was a bad expression :) Well it was just an information that could've been useful. I've thought about that. Not sure it will give much though. It's only one call to execute the query. I will however try it out. It's a great tool! Things i'm concerned about: is it due to locking? Or is it simply the database running out of resources?

Comment: Have you checked for missing indexes, wrong query plan or outdated statistics ? see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/15549211/1236044

Answer (score 0):

Why not call ISession.Clear once in awhile? It will remove all entries from first level cache,  which you probably won't need. Or better, use an IStatelessSession instead of a regular ISession.