# Fluent Nhibernate QueryOver take a long time for getting data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I created an Asp.Net MVC 5 web application using SQL Server 2014 and uses Fluent Nhibernate as ORM.

I have a problem with execution of `QueryOver` queries. Execution of the query takes a very long time.

I get generated SQL query from `Nhibernate` and execute it in SQL Server Management Studio, in this case query executes very fast.

What is problem with Nhibernate `QueryOver`? I used `Fluent Nhibernate` with Oracle in my previous project and this problem not occur there.

Here is my example with `QueryOver` (on SQL Server):

```
Language languageAlias = null;
Slider sliderAlias = null;

var query = QueryOver.Of(() => sliderAlias)
                    .Left
                    .JoinAlias(() => sliderAlias.Language, () => languageAlias)
                    .Where(() => languageAlias.Name == language && !sliderAlias.IsDelete);
```

And in `Repository` I execute this query as:

```
result = query.GetExecutableQueryOver(Session).List();
```

Does anyone have any advice? Thanks.

**Edited:** 
Mappings are:

```
public class LanguageMap : ClassMap<Language>
    {
        public LanguageMap()
        {
            Table("LANGUAGES");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Custom<EntityGuidIdGenerator>().Not.Nullable().Column("Id").CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(32)");

            Map(x => x.Name).Column("NAME").CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(15)");
        }
    }

public class SliderMap : ClassMap<Slider>
    {
        public SliderMap()
        {
            Table("SLIDERS");
            Not.LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Custom<EntityGuidIdGenerator>().Not.Nullable().Column("Id").CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(32)");

            Map(x => x.Title).Column("TITLE").CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(512)");

            Map(x => x.IsDelete).Column("IS_DELETE").CustomSqlType("BIT");

            //references
            References(x => x.Language).Column("LANGUAGE");

            HasMany(x => x.SliderAttachments)
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .KeyColumn("SLIDER")
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.Delete();
        }
    }

public class SliderAttachmentMap : ClassMap<SliderAttachment>
    {
        public SliderAttachmentMap()
        {
            Table("SLIDER_ATTACHMENTS");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Custom<EntityGuidIdGenerator>().Not.Nullable().Column("Id").CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(32)");

            References(x => x.Slider).Nullable().Column("SLIDER");

            References(x => x.Attachment).Nullable().Column("ATTACHMENT");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add you mappings for `Language` and `Slider`: there may some clues there.

Comment: Do you know how to enable NH's logging? It's probably worth taking a look at what NH is doing with the results. If the query's quick then NH must be doing some extra work to create the latency.

Comment: @DavidOsborne I don't use NHibernate NLog on project. I'll use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query executed from Nhibernate is slow, but from ADO.NET is fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753618/query-executed-from-nhibernate-is-slow-but-from-ado-net-is-fast)

Comment: To ascertain this is not a duplicate of the above, use a profiler for checking this is not the db which is slow when called by your application. If a profiler shows bad timings on the db side, then you are very likely in a similar case than above link. This usually boils down to missing indexes causing the db to use a bad query plan in some circumstances, encountered by your application but not encountered when you query your db directly with the same request.

Comment: I created Database Views and map it in NHibernate.Then queries become faster